# Error deploying rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am following the rails tutorial, and I am at a point where it instructs to deploy the app to heroku for the second time. I have successfully deployed an app in the past, but it will not work now.

I get this error : Permission denied (public key)
                    fatal: could not read from remote repository.

The remote exists and is correct, and when using the "heroku key" my key appears. I can add a new stack to heroku as well. I also tried re-adding the key, and that did not work.

Very confused, all the solutions I have found have not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to configure your ssh keys (usually located at ~/.ssh).  Are you using github?  If so, your ssh keys should already be set up (you won't be able to push to github.com without setting those up).

If you haven't already set up your ssh keys, follow [these instructions from github](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) to do so.

Once your ssh keys are set up, performing the command 'git push heroku' should do the trick.  Make sure Heroku is set up correctly by following the [instructions from the tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#sec-heroku_setup)

Comment: That seems to have fixed the ssh problem, but now I am getting  a new error.  "Failed to install gems via Bundler" "Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app"

Comment: I googled the answer and managed to fix it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not deploying as the same user you deployed the first app as.  If you are in a linux environment this probably means you deployed as root one time and tried to as a user the other time, maybe you used sudo .

Or possibly you deleted your ssh public keys....or maybe you changed the permissions of your ssh keys.

I am not high enough rated to comment, so please navigate to ~/.ssh and type "ls -l" so I can see your permissions.  Then navigate one directory up to ~/ and type "ls -la" so I can see your permissions on the actual .ssh folder

then navigate to /.ssh and do the same permissions posting so I can see them.